# Error when converting .obj to openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

When I was converting .obj file to openGL i have some errors. I am not sure how to fix the error. I have change the sign to >, yet the error still persists.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: LoadObj Trial, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  LoadObj Trial.cpp
1>LoadObj Trial.cpp(78): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>LoadObj Trial.cpp(90): error C4996: 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          D:\VISUAL STUDIO\VC\include\stdio.h(311) : see declaration of 'sscanf'
1>LoadObj Trial.cpp(109): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>LoadObj Trial.cpp(134): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>LoadObj Trial.cpp(136): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>LoadObj Trial.cpp(138): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>LoadObj Trial.cpp(140): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Thank you Sir Andon M. Coleman. Sorry sir, quite unclear. Where is the project setting in VC++. I can find the column.

Answer (score 2):

> LoadObj Trial.cpp(90): error C4996: 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
>
> > 1>          D:\VISUAL STUDIO\VC\include\stdio.h(311) : see declaration of 'sscanf'

That is not really an error, and it has got nothing to do with OpenGL. That is the MSVC compiler treating [a level 3 security/deprecation warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys.aspx) as a compiler error. Your project is probably configured to treat level 3/4 warnings as errors.

To solve the "error", you can use the variant it suggest (which will make your code rather non-portable), or simply add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` or add that definition to your pre-processor definitions in the project settings.

The other ***warnings***, however, are impossible to diagnose without seeing your code. And it is pretty safe to assume that simply switching the direction of the comparison is not going to do anything *useful*, that will probably break things and will do nothing to solve the problem of comparing signed and unsigned values.

---

#### Regarding making the pre-processor definition I mentioned a project-wide setting, see the following screenshot (Visual Studio 2013 Pro):

[image: Project Settings]

Comment: @user3557114: Yeah, `std::vector <...>::size ()` generally returns something like `size_t`, which is unsigned. `int` by itself is usually signed. You could use an iterator to loop through the elements, write your loop this way: `std::vector <...>::size_type i = 0` or just use `size_t i` to avoid this compiler warning. The warning is pretty unimportant in this code since you only ever ***increase*** the value of **i** and it is doubtful you will ever have enough elements in your vector to cause a signed overflow.

Comment: glEndList();
        //delete everything to avoid memory leaks
        for(int i=0;i < coord.size();i++)
                delete coord[i];
        for(int i=0;i < faces.size();i++)
                delete faces[i];
        for(int i=0;i < normals.size();i++)
                delete normals[i];
        for(int i=0;i < vertex.size();i++)
                delete vertex[i];
        return num;     //return with the id